# Hide a collection of images one by one with an interval of time

Tags: jquery

i have collection of images in a div block

i want to hide them one by one with an interval of time.

i tried with this script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    delayInSeconds = 1;
    i = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        while (i < 10) {
            $(".images").eq(i).hide();
            i++;
        }
    }, delayInSeconds * 50);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the value of `i` is 10 by the time the first iteration even starts.

One way to solve it is:

```
...
function hideOne(i) {
    $(".images").eq(i).hide();
    if($(".images").eq(i+1).length > 0) { // or change to if(i+1 < 10) if you're sure
        setTimeout(function() { 
            hideOne(i+1);
        }, delayInSeconds * 1000); // given the variable name, the multiplier should be 1000, i believe
    }
}

hideOne(0); // start it
...
```

Comment: can u pls tell what changes to be done to my container<div class="content">
       <div class="images">
        <div id="panel"><img src="panel/1.png"></div></div>
 
        <div class="images">
        <div id="panel"><img src="panel/2.png"></div></div>

        <div class="images">
        <div id="panel"><img src="panel/3.png"></div></div>
 
        <div class="images">
        <div id="panel"><img src="panel/4.png"></div></div>
  
        <div class="images">
        <div id="panel"><img src="panel/5.png"></div></div>
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".images").each(function(){
  setTimeOut($(this).hide(),300);
 });
});
```

This should do that.
Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

This will do it. It makes use of the `:visible` selector to discard hidden images, and the `:eq(0)` selector to grab a single element from the matches set.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Khm68/)

```
var delayInSeconds = 1;

function hide(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var images = $('.images:visible:eq(0)');
        if(images.length == 1){
            images.hide();
            hide();
        }

    }, 1000 * delayInSeconds);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    hide();
});
```